# Can anyone tell me what this wooden clamp might be used for?

Tags: woodworking

I have two of these wooden clamp devices but I have no idea what they are specifically used for. Does anyone have info?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Perhaps show the whole thing, not just one end of it?

Comment: We'll need to see full length, various angles, and how far the short end pivots, any grooves, holes and mention where you found them, what other tools/materials were there, type of workshop etc...

Comment: Does the handle lock it into place? This looks like a tool to measure an angle.

Comment: how would you clamp anything in that?

Comment: @Olivier  Can make that an answer.  More to copy than measure.

Comment: That would make for an extremely heavy-duty angle finder. I suspect furniture, but it's hard to say from this one view.

Comment: Are you sure this is a tool, rather than a part of something?  Can we see pictures from different angles including end views?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like an old angle finder. It will obviously not measure angles like the modern versions with a digital readout but it can be used to replicate them.

An example use would be to mark the cut for siding on a gable end.

Comment: From the limited view we have of it, this seems very likely

Comment: yes, place it, lock-in the angle, then use it as a cutting or scoring guide. considering it's not banged up, I'd guess for indoor use, maybe flooring/carpet or shelving

Comment: The fact that the short end protrudes means it's not a lot of good for inside angles, less than 180deg!

Comment: @Tim I agree it's a little weird. Especially with the handle. Better versions have been available for a longer time than the apparent age of this thing. So it could be something else too.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is an angle measure/copy tool because of the shorter end, however you could maybe still use it to copy an angle.

to me, this looks more like an arm to hold something else at an angle. such as a camera or light stand. if there are threaded inserts in the ends (not visible in picture) this might support that idea.

like some mentioned, perhaps furniture because it looks like it has a stain finish applied to it that wouldn't necessarily be used on a tool.